# Which is quicker in psql: 2 inserts from selects, or one insert from union of selects?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, insert

As in the title: I have a table that I need to populate. I have two sources of data to put in that table. Which will be quicker:

```
INSERT INTO foo
SELECT bar, baz FROM xxxx;

INSERT INTO foo
SELECT beq, que FROM yyyyy;
```

OR:

```
INSERT INTO foo
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT bar, baz FROM xxxx
UNION
SELECT beq, que FROM yyyyy ) src;
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: you queries are not equal, because `union` will remove duplicates, you may want to use `union all` if you want all of your rows to be inserted, so I'd say first one will be quicker because it's simple inserts without checking duplicates :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say `union all` would be faster than two inserts, just because it's one transaction instead of two, but I'm not DBA at all, and I guess it could depend on number of rows / types of columns in the tables. Tested on SQL fiddle on PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on 2 table with 1 000 000 records each. Results:

2 inserts ~ **2600** ms
1 insert with union ~ **10800** ms - *eliminating duplicates is expensive*!
1 insert with union all ~ **2460** ms

see it on [**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a9a98/1)

Answer (score 1):

In my case (inserting ~7500 rows), the difference was about 2secs (UNION ALL was quicker).